# Java reflection; how to use Method.invoke() to retrieve an Object array?

Tags: java, reflection

I need some help using reflection in Java.  I need to use reflection to call a method that returns an Object array. `Method.invoke()` only returns an Object. How is this done?

Many thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 6):

You just have to cast the return value of Method.invoke() to whatever you happen to know it is. Not very robust, but such are the risks of reflection! So in this case, it would be:

```
Object[] result = (Object[]) method.invoke(...);
```

Btw, note that if the method returns a primitive (`int`, `double`, etc), `Method.invoke` will return its boxed equivalent (`Integer`, `Double`, etc).

Comment: @user1084636: Accept one of these as the answer!

Answer (score 0):

An `Object[]` is an object--cast the result of `invoke` to `Object[]`.